# Get listitems from Current Site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to create a Page Layout, that should have a lookup field. Lookup field should always get populated with a list's items.

This list will exist in all subsites, so whereever I create this page, list should get populated with listitems from current site.

I tried using site column lookup field, but it always point to list under top site and not the current site.

Any suggestion on how to make it work or better alternative? Thanks!

Let me know if I can provide more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward solution I can think of is using a cross site lookup column and creating a seperate fields for each subsite. However, you will need to create and use different Page Layouts for each subsite.

You can use http://sp2010filteredlookup.codeplex.com/ for cross site lookups.

Comment: Thanks for comment BloodRavens. I think it will be a maintenance nightmare to create different page layouts for every subsite. If I end up doing so, I wouldn't need cross site lookup.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1** - Use http://sp2010filteredlookup.codeplex.com/

Use filtered lookup solution. So let's say you have your custom Page Layout and custom Page Content Type.
Every time you create new subsite, you should remember go to Pages list settings and edit Page Content Type by adding cross site lookup (with the same field "internal name").
So you still have one Page Layout (and one Content Type). But for each Pages library instance, Content Type contains diff fields (but with the same Internal Name). It will allow you run CAML queries and other things needed without any problems.

**Solution 2** - develop custom sharepoint field type.

In edit mode, control will render "dropdown list" and populate data from list instance that is on current subsite. In the field settings you can have relative list url.

**Solution 3** - hidden text field / js snippet solution

Page Content Type can contain hidden text field (it can contains selected field value in json format for example). Develop js snippet that will handle all the logic (rendering in edit/view mode, saving etc) and put it on Page Layout (aspx).

I would suggest to use solution #1 or #2.